# How can i convert from logical coordinate to device in java

Tags: java

I read wireframe applet example bundled with jdk examples but I didn't understanded how it converted from logical to device coordinate system.

For example, if I want to set the coordinate system to center of screen I use the following code:

```
int iX(float x) {
  return Math.round(centerX + x/pixelSize);
}
int iY(float y) {
  return Math.round(centerY - y/pixelSize);
}
float fx(int x) {
  return (x - centerX) * pixelSize;
}
float fy(int y){
  return (centerY - y) * pixelSize;
}
```

Is it possible a way to draw without this conversion?

Comment: An example of what you're trying to do might help us understand what you want.

Comment: if i want to set coordinate system to center of screen i use the following code for it.
is it possible a way to draw without this conversion
    int iX(float x){return Math.round(centerX + x/pixelSize);}
    int iY(float y){return Math.round(centerY - y/pixelSize);}

    float fx(int x){return (x - centerX) * pixelSize;}
    float fy(int y){return (centerY - y) * pixelSize;}